# SSIS - Flat File with escape characters

Tags: file, csv, ssis, flat

I have a large flat file I'm using to recover data.  It was exported from a system using double quotes " as the qualifier and a pipe | a the delimiter.  SSIS can be configured to this without a problem, but where I'm running into issues is with the \ escape char.

the row causing the issue:

```
"125004267"|"125000316"|"125000491"|"height"|"5' 11\""|"12037"|"46403"|""|"t"|""|"2012-10-01 22:34:01"|"2012-10-01 22:34:01"|"1900-01-01 00:00:00"
```

The fourth column in the database should be 5' 11".

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: 0xC0202055 at Data Flow Task 1, Flat File Source [2]: The column delimiter for column "posting_value" was not found.

How can I tell SSIS to handle the `\` escape character?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I just ran into a similar issue regarding escaping quotes in CSV's in SSIS. It seems odd there isn't more flexible support for this but it does support VB-style double-double quotes. So in your example you could pre-parse the file to translate it into

```
"125004267"|"125000316"|"125000491"|"height"|"5' 11"""|"12037"|"46403"|""|"t"|""|"2012-10-01 22:34:01"|"2012-10-01 22:34:01"|"1900-01-01 00:00:00"
```

to get your desired output. This at least works on Sql Server 2014.

This also works for Excel (tested with 2010). Though, oddly, only when inserting data from a text file, not when opening a CSV with Excel.

This does appear to be the standardized method according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)
which states

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
> should be enclosed in double-quotes

...

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.

Comment: Escaping double quotes with double quotes seems to break SSIS for us.

Comment: I was unable to find documentation of this so I suppose this technique is officially "Works on My Machine" certified.

Comment: Yeah, not too sure why.  For our data, replacing them with single quotes was an acceptable work around.

Comment: Added some info after some more searching

Answer (score -1):

This probably isn't the answer you are looking for, but...

I'd reach out to the technical contacts of the source of data, and explain to them that if they're going to send you a file that uses double-quotes as text qualifiers, then that implies that there are never any double-quotes in the text.  If that is possible, as it happens here, tell them to use another text qualifier, or none at all.

Since there are pipe delimeters in use, what's the point of having text qualifiers? 
Seems redundant.

Comment: This isn't so true.  The use of double quotes as text qualifiers does not imply there are no double quotes in the content.  It is common (de-facto standard even ?) to use double quotes to escape double quotes in the content.

Comment: Good point.  My experience though (  just mine, ymmv ) when this happens is that developers of the file are more willing to change the delimeter character then to write the code to insert escape characters into the content.